# (Python) Running shell commands on a separate window OS X (subprocess)

Tags: python, macos, shell, networking

I work in a networking department and am trying to simplify the process of wiping and updating switches. The current method is to use a Mac OSX computer to console to a USB->Serial adapter and copy and paste the commands on the switch. For example:

```
sudo cu -l /dev/cu.usbserial -s 9600
(password)
enable
conf t
...
copy tftp flash 192.168.1.2 FCX_8030h_boot.bin bootrom
...
```

We often have to update large numbers of these switches and the process of copy/paste can take a significant amount of time. To speed things up, I started working on a Python script to try and automate it, or at least allow for a guided input process.

I'm stuck on the first bit of code:

```
import subprocess
...
subprocess.call("sudo cu -l /dev/cu.usbserial -s 9600", shell=True)
```

(Note: I'm aware of the risks of shell=True, but this will be used on a local, non-networked machine using string literals rather than user input)

This command works...running the script opens a terminal window, then runs the command. The problem is that I cannot return to the script; the new process takes over everything, and I'm stuck just typing commands in manually to the switch.

I tried Popen() instead of call() but the line does not appear to do anything at all; instead it exits the script with a standard error code (no visible errors).

Preferably I would like to open a new shell window in the background and have the original script able to enter commands into that shell, so the user gets feedback on the process but maintains control from the script. If that isn't possible, I need a way to echo the content from the switch without losing access to the script input.

So far I've researched OPEN_NEW_CONSOLE, but apparently this only works on a Windows system (the Mac is unfortunately my only option at work). The commands for opening new console windows using Popen, such as "cmd" or "xterm" do not appear to work for OSX, and I have not found an alternative (or do not know what to look for specifically). All questions I've seen regarding subprocess, including the official documentation, seem to assume the process will be completed and return a value, but I need the process to continue while retaining control (and preferably visibility) from the original script.

Is this possible? Is there another language besides Python which would work better for this? Thank you in advance for your help, and I apologize if there is a better answer and I didn't know where to look.

Comment: See if os.system works for you. I know it is deprecated, but you may want to check it out.

Comment: yes, first import os, then `os.system('sudo cu -l /dev/cu.usbserial -s 9600;nextcommand;nextcommand')`